# Specifying ssh key in ansible playbook file

Tags: ansible

Ansible playbook can specify the key used for ssh connection using `--key-file` on the command line.

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --key-file "~/.ssh/mykey.pem"
```

Is it possible to specify the location of this key in playbook file instead of using `--key-file` on command line?

Because I want to write the location of this key into a `var.yaml` file, which will be read by ansible playbook with `vars_files:`.

The followings are parts of my configuration:

vars.yml file

```
key1: ~/.ssh/mykey1.pem
key2: ~/.ssh/mykey2.pem
```

playbook.yml file

```
---

- hosts: myHost
  remote_user: ubuntu
  key_file: {{ key1 }}  # This is not a valid syntax in ansible. Does there exist this kind of directive which allows me to specify the ssh key used for this connection?
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Echo a hello message
      command: echo hello
```

I've tried adding `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` under `vars`. But it doesn't work on my machine.

```
vars_files:
  - vars.yml
vars:
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ key1 }}"
tasks:
  - name: Echo a hello message
    command: echo hello
```

If I run `ansible-playbook` with the `playbook.yml` above. I got the following error:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<192.168.5.100> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<192.168.5.100> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ubuntu -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/myName/.ansible/cp/2d18691789 192.168.5.100 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.5.100> (255, '', 'Permission denied (publickey).\r\n')
fatal: [192.168.5.100]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/myName/playbook.retry
```

I don't find the name of my key file in the ssh command. It's strange.

Comment: I think `--private-key=~/.ssh/keys/id_rsa` will work.

Comment: @zx1986 `--private-key key_file_path` worked for me too.

Answer (score 178):

The variable name you're looking for is `ansible_ssh_private_key_file`.

You should set it at 'vars' level:

- in the inventory file:

  ```
  myHost ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/mykey1.pem
  myOtherHost ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/mykey2.pem
  ```
- in the `host_vars`:

  ```
  # host_vars/myHost.yml
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/mykey1.pem

  # host_vars/myOtherHost.yml
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/mykey2.pem
  ```
- in a `group_vars` file if you use the same key for a group of hosts
- in the `vars` section of an entry in a play:

  ```yaml
  - hosts: myHost
     remote_user: ubuntu
     vars_files:
       - vars.yml
     vars:
       ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ key1 }}"
     tasks:
       - name: Echo a hello message
         command: echo hello
  ```
- in *setting a fact* in a play entry (task):

  ```yaml
  - name: 'you name it'
     ansible.builtin.set_fact:
       ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ key1 }}"
  ```

[Inventory documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#behavioral-parameters)

Comment: Writing `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` under `vars` doesn't work on my machine. It's strange.

Comment: I don't want to specify the key in the inventory. Because I can't load `vars.yml` from the inventory file.

Comment: Exact: from the `vars` it's simply too late I think.
You should use `host_vars` or `group_vars` files then if you don't want to put this in your inventory.

Comment: It would be kind of interesting to see the best practice of having the private key in a vault, so the private key can be pushed into the git repo without feeling that bad.

Comment: @fabiog You're right, I just tested it withAnsible 2.9 down to 1.8 and all (major) versions works with the private key defined in `vars:` section.

Answer (score 63):

You can use the ansible.cfg file, it should look like this (There are other parameters which you might want to include):

```
[defaults]
inventory = <PATH TO INVENTORY FILE>
remote_user = <YOUR USER>
private_key_file =  <PATH TO KEY_FILE>
```

Hope this saves you some typing

Comment: For goofy lab environments with project specific configs and keys, this is by far the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you run your playbook with `ansible-playbook -vvv` you'll see the actual command being run, so you can check whether the key is actually being included in the ssh command (and you might discover that the problem was the wrong username rather than the missing key).

I agree with Brian's comment above (and zigam's edit) that the vars section is too late.  I also tested including the key in the on-the-fly definition of the host like this

```
# fails
- name: Add all instance public IPs to host group
  add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groups=ec2hosts ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.aws/dev_staging.pem
  loop: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

but that fails too.

So this is not an answer.  Just some debugging help and things not to try.